# STm32 and GPS module

Tags: gps, stm32

Can anyone please explain how to establish a communication between stm32 dev board and gps module? I am not knowing how to send AT commands to gps module through MC through a source file through UART. Please clarify me in this aspect.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of literature on STM32 and UARTs on the web. If I were you I would download the [STM32CubeMX](http://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubemx.html). This program generates most of the code for you. You select your processor (or development board), select the clocks and peripherals, and click `Generate Code`. It also comes with very handy example projects, and might even have a complete project with a working UART that you can put straight onto your board.

And I would first make sure my UART is fully working before connecting the GPS. This you can do by trying to echo. Connect your TX and RX pins with a wire. Then, everything you transmit you will receive as well. It's a easy test to see if everything is working.

I would also work through the [TrueStudio IDE](https://atollic.com/resources/download/). It basically works plug and play

Answer (score 0):

If you use the ublox module, you must use a serial port to communicate.
You have to connect RXD(ublox) to TXD(micro) and TXD(Ublox) to RXD(micro) ,
and config your StmCubemx like This :

http://wiki.sunfounder.cc/index.php?title=Ublox_NEO-6M_GPS_Module

Config Stm32 :

[Step 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1B4Ed.jpg ]

[Step 2:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ULOm.jpg]

[Step 3:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/GD0VL.jpg]

If you have another question, please ask

Comment: Hi Mahdi, you mind putting the gist of the answer in your post instead of linking to external page? (and link to it as complementary reading)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you should test AT command with module sim through (USB to UART) to PC in order to understand procedure operation, such as: module sim - TCP/IP - thingspeak server. The next time, you can refer this link for code: https://bitbucket.org/mbari_peter/sim800-mqtt-ravi/src/78e36076c89b4618cf57a538f0c70f91b2b876dd/modemDrivers.ino?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default
If you have any questions or encounter any problems, you can ask! Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

Typically, GPS sends data @ 1 Hz after starting up. You just need to capture this NMEA sentences and filter the receive buffer according to your requirement.

Try using UART receive interrupt. Make sure the baud rate of both GPS module and STM32 are same.